# How to select many from string in efcore?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, expression-trees

Say there is a palette

```
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
| 1  | pa     |
| 2  | pb     |
+----+--------+
```

of colors.

```
+----+------+------------+
| id | name | palette_id |
+----+------+------------+
| 1  | ca   |  1         |
| 2  | cb   |  2         |
+----+------+------------+
```

To select and filter paletts I can use:

```
_dbContext.Palettes.Where(p => p.Colors.Any(x => x.Name.Contains("ca"))
```

However I would like to construct this from a string. Given a string like `Colors.Name` and  `ca`, how can I create an efcore expression, that returns all palettes where color names match `ca`?

The use case for this is, that I have a filter efcore extension that takes a string and converts that into an efcore expression.

```
_dbContext.Palettes.Filter("Colors.Name contains ca")...
```

Comment: Is what you need to get the palettes that have `ca` color, or to get all `ca` colors, existing in any palette?

Comment: To clarify question, why not just `_dbContext.Colors.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("ca"))`?

Comment: Are you asking how to create `string.Contains` call expression instead of `Equal`? If yes, simply use `Expression.Call(property, "Contains", Type.EmptyTypes, valueExpression)`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I guess my example was confusing. What I literally want to know is, how to create this _dbContext.Palettes.SelectMany(x => x.Colors).Where(x => x.Name.Contains("ca")); manually by using expressions. Because later on I will do _dbContext.Paletts.Filter("Colors.Name contains ca"). The filter will be converted into an efcore expression.

Comment: Still unclear. Filter should not change resultset type. Why not `_dbContext.Palettes.Where(p => p.Colors.Any(x => x.Name.Contains("ca"))` ?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv thanks for making things clear :) I actually want to return palettes, where any of the color names matches ca. So you are right. Can you compile an answer on how to achieve something like "_dbContext.Palettes.Where(p => p.Colors.Any(x => x.Name.Contains("ca"))" using expressions?

Comment: Will prepare function `FilterContains(propPath, value)`, other filters - your work. Do you expect Deeper nesting of your properties?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv thx! No, deeper nesting is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented two methods `FilterContains` and `FilterEquals`. I think it will be easy to extend them.

Function takes care about any nesting level and generates proper filter, but it requires to pass `DbContext` for using Model information:

```cs
_dbContext.Palettes.FilterContains(_dbContext, "Colors.Name", "ca")
   .ToList();
_dbContext.Palettes.FilterEquals(_dbContext, "Colors.Name", "ca")
   .ToList();
```

But it also can handle something like this:

```cs
_dbContext.Users.FilterContains(_dbContext, "Country.Regions.SubRegions.Name", "ca")
   .ToList();
```

And implementation:

```cs
public static class DynamicQueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> FilterContains<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, DbContext context, string propPath, string value)
    {
        return FilterQuery(query, context.Model, propPath, propExpression =>
            Expression.Call(EnsureString(propExpression), nameof(string.Contains), Type.EmptyTypes,
                Expression.Constant(value)));
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> FilterEquals<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, DbContext context, string propPath, object? value)
    {
        return FilterQuery(query, context.Model, propPath, propExpression =>
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                var propType = propExpression.Type;
                if (propType.IsValueType)
                {
                    propExpression = Expression.Convert(propExpression, typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(propType));
                }
            }
            else if (propExpression.Type != value.GetType())
            {
                value = Convert.ChangeType(value, propExpression.Type);
            }

            return Expression.Equal(propExpression, Expression.Constant(value, propExpression.Type));
        });
    }

    private static IQueryable<T> FilterQuery<T>(IQueryable<T> query, IModel model, string propPath,
        Func<Expression, Expression> filterFactory)
    {
        var propNames = propPath.Split('.');

        var entityParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");

        var filter = BuildFilter(entityParameter, model, propNames, 0, filterFactory);

        var filterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(filter, entityParameter);

        return query.Where(filterLambda);
    }

    private static Expression BuildFilter(Expression obj, IModel model, string[] propPath, int currentIndex, Func<Expression, Expression> predicateFactory)
    {
        var entityType = model.FindEntityType(obj.Type);

        var propName = propPath[currentIndex];

        var prop = entityType.FindProperty(propName);

        Expression filter;

        if (prop == null)
        {
            var navigation = entityType.GetNavigations().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == propName);

            if (navigation == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Property '{propName}' not found in type '{obj.Type}'");

            var navigationAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(obj, navigation.PropertyInfo);

            if (navigation.IsCollection)
            {
                var targetType = navigation.TargetEntityType.ClrType;
                var nParam = Expression.Parameter(targetType, "n");
                var anyFilter = BuildFilter(nParam, model, propPath, currentIndex + 1, predicateFactory);

                filter = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.Any), new[] { targetType }, navigationAccess, Expression.Lambda(anyFilter, nParam));
            }
            else
            {
                filter = BuildFilter(navigationAccess, model, propPath, currentIndex + 1, predicateFactory);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var propAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(obj, prop.PropertyInfo);
            filter = predicateFactory(propAccess);
        }

        return filter;
    }

    // For safe conversion to string
    private static Expression EnsureString(Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression.Type == typeof(string))
            return expression;

        if (expression.Type != typeof(object))
            expression = Expression.Convert(expression, typeof(object));

        expression = Expression.Call(_toStringMethod, expression);

        return expression;
    }

    private static MethodInfo _toStringMethod = typeof(Convert).GetMethods()
        .Single(m =>
            m.Name == nameof(Convert.ToString) && m.GetParameters().Length == 1 &&
            m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(object)
        );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that beautiful solution! I am not sure tho how to incorporate that into my use case. I actually don't need it to be that dynamic. Have a look at line 134 in https://pastebin.com/fkkXgkQx Can you make it similar to e.g. line 142?

Comment: I have no access to your link.

Comment: Try again. It should work now.

Comment: `This site can’t be reached` - use something else for sharing code.

Comment: Okay, try this one https://paste.ee/p/UwD7C

Comment: Actually you can use `var right = BuildFilter(parameterExpression, _dbContext, field.Split('.'), 0,  propExpression =>
            Expression.Call(EnsureString(propExpression), nameof(string.Contains), Type.EmptyTypes,
                Expression.Constant(value)))`. But you have to remove `property` calculation, it will fail.

Comment: Function traverse properties and calls factory method when needed.

Comment: Thanks, that's very powerful. I might ask another question to fully understand how the filter is built.

Comment: Use [ReadableExpressions.Visualizers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1232914.ReadableExpressionsVisualizers) and you can easy debug this recursive function.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same result without passing dbcontext?

Comment: Better to pass `IModel`, we can accurately read metadata information. But yes, it is possible.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it without imodel here ?:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73499563/argumentexception-when-trying-to-translate-efcore-expression-to-expression-trees ?