# How could I generate a c# .NET core function that can mimic the Include().ThenInclude.(Where) behaviour?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, recursion, reflection, expression-trees

I'm trying to create a generic blazor component that and has a config object.
So far I've been able to successfully mimic .Where(), .Include().ThenInclude() separately, but now I need to add condition to the include.

My config file has the following structure

```cs
class Config 
{
    public List<string> includes {get;set;}
    public List<Expression<Func<T,bool>>> conditions {get;set;}
}
```

---

**database structure**

For the example lets assume the following structure.

```
Dataset (1)<--(n) DatasetItem 
DatasetItem (1)-->(1) Image
DatasetItem (1)-->(1) Label
Image (1)<--(n) Labels
Label(1)<--(n) Tags
```

where an image can be a part of more than one dataset and it's tags might or might not be included in the same dataset. Imagine an picture of a city park with dogs, people, and cars. Someone would want a dataset of vehicles and consider only the cars and ignore the labels about animals and people.

A Label include the coordinates and one or more TagNames (vehicle, car, red, fourWheeler, etc)

---

**what works**

And I can give conditions and includes this way:

```cs
var config = new Config<DatasetItem>()
{
    includes = new() {"Image", "Image.Labels", "Image.Labels.Tags"}
    conditions = new() {di => di.datasetId == 1, di => di.Label.width > 100}
}
```

---

**the problems and limitations of this approach**

For this to work I use the .Include(str) overload, but I don't like that approach since it is prone to fail.

The other problem with this approach is a limitation on the conditions.
For example, I can not add a condition to get only the Tags that belong to a specific category.

It seems that is not possible to add a condition that would give me this filter. Best I got was with the use of All or Any, but those do not give the desire result.

```cs
config.conditions.Add(
    di => di.Images.Any(i => Labels.Any(l => l.Tags.Any(t => t.Name == "vehicle"))
)
```

---

**what I'm looking for**

Whith regular use of Include, obtaining the desire result would be like this.

```cs
DatasetItems.Include(di => di.Images)
    .ThenInclude(i => i.Labels)
    .ThenInclude(l => l.Tags.Where(t => t.Name == "vehicle"))
```

So, is there any way to achieve this?
I thing the solution would require to use Expression Trees, Reflection, and Recursive functions using MakeGenericMethod, but I havent found a way to achive this.

the ideal solution would be to find a structure like the one for conditions
`List<Expression<Func<T,something>>>` that lets me add the condition in this way

```cs
includes.add(di => di.Images.Labels.Tags.Where(t => t.Name == "vehicle"))
```

---

**a failed attempt**

I'm including a failed attempt I took to solve this, just in case this helps to narrow down the intention and for if someone can use it for solving the problem. This attempt is far from ideal.

property was a dot-separated string, like "Image.Labels.Tags" and filter was suppoused to be the Where expression.
This function does not compile.

```cs
public static IQueryable<T> FilteredInclude<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string property, Func<dynamic, bool> filter) where T : class
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var properties = property.Split('.');
    var propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(properties[0]);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
    var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyInfo);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(propertyExpression, parameter);

    var filteredQuery = query.Where(x => filter(propertyInfo.GetValue(x)));

    if (properties.Length == 1)
    {
        var methodInfo = typeof(QueryableExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(Include));
        methodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(type, propertyInfo.PropertyType);
        var result = methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { filteredQuery, lambda });

        return (IQueryable<T>)result;
    }
    else
    {
        var nextProperty = string.Join(".", properties.Skip(1));
        var result = filteredQuery.FilteredInclude(nextProperty, filter);

        var thenIncludeMethod = typeof(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.IncludeExpression)
            .GetMethod("ThenInclude")
            .MakeGenericMethod(propertyInfo.PropertyType);

        var resultWithThenInclude = thenIncludeMethod.Invoke(result, new object[] { lambda });

        return (IQueryable<T>)resultWithThenInclude;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check [this my implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73473316/10646316) it will help you to build this filter. But for sure it will not help to create API. Play with just filtering records, then it can be expanded to `Include`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? `Include` isn't a JOIN operation, or even a general-purpose LINQ operation. It's only used by EF Core to determine which objects to load eagerly and which to delay loading until the user asks for them. JOINs are generated by the relations between objects, not `Include`.