# Building an Expression tree for navigation property item in code

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I am working with VS2022 and use EF Core. My data context is _myLab05Context, I have an entity "Solution" which has a navigation property "SolutionUsages". SolutionUsages has a property "StudyId". For example I want to retrieve all solutions with SolutionUsages.StudyId == 5. I can do this with the following code:

```
                var query = await _myLab05Context.Solutions
                .Select(s => new
                {
                    Solutions = s,
                    SolutionUsages = s.SolutionUsages.Where(su => su.StudyId == 5)
                })
                .Where(s => s.SolutionUsages.Any(su => su.StudyId == 5))
                .ToListAsync();
```

which works fine. As a first step for the dynamic approach I generated two expressions:

```
            var anyQuery =
                _buildWhereExpression.GenericAny<Entities.Solution, Entities.SolutionUsage>("SolutionUsages",
                    "StudyId", 5L);

            var whereQuery =
                _buildWhereExpression.GenericWhere<Entities.Solution, Entities.SolutionUsage>("SolutionUsages",
                    "StudyId", 5L);
```

anyQuery is of type Expression<Func<Entities.Solution, bool>>, and whereQuery is of type Expression<Func<SolutionUsage, bool>> and they contain exactly the syntax of the "manual" where-clauses.

```
    public Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> GenericAny<TSource, T2ndSource>(string navPropName, string propName, long propValue)
    {
        ParameterExpression pe02 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2ndSource), "x");
        MemberExpression me02 = Expression.Property(pe02, propName);
        ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(propValue);
        BinaryExpression body = Expression.Equal(me02, constant);
        var funcExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T2ndSource, bool>>(body, pe02);


        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource), "s");
        MemberExpression me = Expression.Property(pe, navPropName);
        var navPropType = typeof(T2ndSource);
        var anyCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.Any), new[] { navPropType }, me, funcExpression);
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(anyCall, pe);

        return predicate;
    }

    public Expression<Func<T2ndSource, bool>> GenericWhere<TSource, T2ndSource>(string navPropName, string propName, long propValue)
    {
        ParameterExpression pe02 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T2ndSource), "x");
        MemberExpression me02 = Expression.Property(pe02, propName);
        ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(propValue);
        BinaryExpression body = Expression.Equal(me02, constant);
        var funcExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T2ndSource, bool>>(body, pe02);

        return funcExpression;
    }
```

(I know whereQuery is already part of anyQuery, but I held them separately to separate the errors.)

When I replace the first where-clause with "whereQuery", I get one error in the line with "where":

> Error  CS1929  "ICollection" contains no definition for "Where", and the  overload of the optimal extension methode "Queryable.Where(IQueryable, Expression<Func<SolutionUsage, bool>>)" requires a recipient of Typ "System.Linq.IQueryable<myBlazorLab_g.Entities.SolutionUsage>".  (translated from German).

When I replace the second where clause with "anyQuery", I get the error

> Error CS1503   Argument "2": Conversion from "System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<myBlazorLab_g.Entities.Solution, bool>>" into "System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<<anonymous type: myBlazorLab_g.Entities.Solution Solutions, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<myBlazorLab_g.Entities.SolutionUsage> SolutionUsages>, int, bool>>" is impossible.

How can I modify the Expressions so that they will work in the query?

**Edit:** the relevant part of my model is
[image]

and the entities are

```
public partial class Solution
{
    [Key]
    public long SolutionId { get; set; }
    [Required] public string SolName { get; set; }
    public long Extension { get; set; }
    public DateTime PrepareDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public long PreparedBy { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("ContainsSol")]
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> IngredientContainsSols { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Solution")]
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> IngredientSolutions { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PreparedBy")]
    [InverseProperty("Solutions")]
    public virtual Person PreparedByNavigation { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Solution")]
    public virtual ICollection<SolutionUsage> SolutionUsages { get; set; }
}


public partial class SolutionUsage
{
    [Key]
    public long UsageId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UseDate { get; set; }
    public long? UsedBy { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public long? SolutionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public long StudyId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SolutionId")]
    [InverseProperty("SolutionUsages")]
    public virtual Solution Solution { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StudyId")]
    [InverseProperty("SolutionUsages")]
    public virtual Study Study { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UsedBy")]
    [InverseProperty("SolutionUsages")]
    public virtual Person UsedByNavigation { get; set; }
}

public partial class Study
{
    [Key]
    public long StudyId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string StudyName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string StudyDescription { get; set; }
    public long CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public long ProjectId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Study")]
    public virtual ICollection<ChemicalUsage> ChemicalUsages { get; } = new List<ChemicalUsage>();
    [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
    [InverseProperty("Studies")]
    public virtual Person CreatedByNavigation { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
    [InverseProperty("Studies")] 
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Study")]
    public virtual ICollection<SolutionUsage> SolutionUsages { get; } = new List<SolutionUsage>();
}
```

What I want is to get a list of all Solutions with a certain SolutionUsages.StudyId. For example, a Solution might have 10 SolutionUsages with 7 different StudyIds, some Solutions might have different Usages (Dates) for the same StudyId. I want to create a master-detail-table which lists all Solution as master, with their SolutionUsages as details, for a distinct StudyId. This is what my first "manual" code snippet does. At the end the program should allow to use other fields than StudyId, and even other ICollections than SolutionUsages, and even other entities than Solution. I hope I could describe my problem now a bit clearer.

Comment: Check this [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73473316/10646316). It has function `FilterEquals`. Actually it generates what you need but is more robust, because can handle any nesting of collection properties.

Comment: Svyatoslav: it's hard for me to understand your code, I am still working on it. "FilterContains" does not work because I pass a long as value, thus EnsureSring-method fails. "FilterEquals" works and seems to return the correct number of Solutions, but the SolutionUsages-property is null instead of returning the SolutionUsages for the given StudyId.

Comment: Post your model in question and will correct code. Probably it is not so easy to understand this, but function do simple thing, generates nested filter recursively. Use [ReadableExpressionsVisualizers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1232914.ReadableExpressionsVisualizers), to examine each generation step.

Comment: Svyatoslav: thank you for your help. Pleas see my edit above.

Comment: `.Call(typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.Any), ...` right... but I'm not seeing where you are `.Call(typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.Where), ...` to give you the `Error CS1929 "ICollection" contains no definition for "Where"` error.

Comment: Well, I see what is needed. Main problem here that we cannot dynamically create anonymous class (we can but with huge efforts). It should be some predefined class.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure if I understand what you are trying to do. Doing this in a dynamic way, is probably going to be a bit messy.

I am not sure I understand your use case. But if your issue is applying the expressions, the last part of this should work fine.

A simple way to do this when knowing the type of the navigation property would be as follows:

```
public static Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> Combine<TSource, TProp, TResult>(
    Expression<Func<TSource, TProp>> selectExpression,
    Expression<Func<TProp, TResult>> transformExpression)
{
    var sourceParameter = propertyExpression.Parameters[0];
    var propertyAccess = propertyExpression.Body;
    var transformedAccess = Expression.Invoke(transformExpression, propertyAccess);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TResult>>(transformedAccess, sourceParameter);
}

public class Solution { public List<Study> SolutionUsages { get; set; } }
public class Study { public int StudyId { get; set; } }
public static void Example()
{
    IQueryable<Solution> solutions = new List<Solution>().AsQueryable();
    var exprWhereAny = ExprHelp.Combine<Solution, List<Study>, bool>(
        container => container.SolutionUsages,
        list => list.Any(s => s.StudyId == 5));

    var exprWhere = ExprHelp.Combine<Solution, List<Study>, IEnumerable<Study>>(
        container => container.SolutionUsages,
        list => list.Where(s => s.StudyId == 5))
        .Compile();

    var query = solutions
        .Where(exprWhereAny)
        .Select(s => new
        {
            Solutions = s,
            SolutionUsages = exprWhere.Invoke(s)
        })
        .ToList();
...
}
```

Hope that this gets you some of the way at least.

Comment: niefio: thank you for your post. Obviously the description of my needs was not clear enough. What I want to achieve in the example is to replace "StudyId" and "5" by values passed into a subroutine which constructs the corresponding expressions. At the moment I am struggling with replacing the entities in your code. Solution is the parent entity, and it has an ICollection<SolutionUsage> SolutionUsages, and SolutionUsage has a property "StudyId". I want to get all of those solutions including their SolutionUsage, where StudyId == 5.