# Create expression trees using generic arguments which involves nested properties

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees, dynamicquery

I am trying to create a dynamic query generator, using generic arguments.

For example:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateExpression<T>(
  ParameterExpression parameter, 
  List<string> properties, 
  object? value, 
  string? operation) where T : class
```

Here `T` is a `Vulnerability` class:

```
public class vulnerability 
{
    public virtual ICollection<VulnCvssMetric> VulnCvssMetrics { get; } = new List<VulnCvssMetric>();
}

public class VulnCvssMetric
{
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

Now I would like dynamically generate this expression, return all the vulnerabilities which have a `VulnCvssMetric` score greater than 5.

The Linq expression would be:

```
DbContext.Set<Vulnerability>().Where(x => x.VulnCvssMetric.Any(y => y.Score > 5))
```

Please find the functions I have written below

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateExpression<T>(ParameterExpression parameter, List<string> properties, object? value, string? operation) where T:class
{
    Expression expression = parameter;

    // case 1: nested properties.
    if (properties.Count() > 1)
    {
        // if the parameter is of type IEnumerable then we have to use the generic type arguments of that Enumerable to get the type.
        // For example ICollection<Vulneribility> -- Generic type argument is Vulnerability which the parameter type.

        bool isCollection = typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(parameter.Type);

        // change the parameter to the actual type, instead of collection.
        // changed from ICollection --> Vulnerability
        var nestedProperties = properties.Skip(1).ToList();

        if (isCollection)
        {
            var parameterType = parameter.Type.GenericTypeArguments[0];
            var nestedParameter = Expression.Parameter(parameterType, parameterType.Name);

            expression = CreateExpression<T>(nestedParameter, nestedProperties, value, operation);

            var anyMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Single(x => x.Name == "Any" && x.GetParameters().Length == 2);
            anyMethod = anyMethod.MakeGenericMethod(nestedParameter.Type);
            var methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(anyMethod, parameter, expression);

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(methodCallExpression, parameter);
        }
        else
        {
            var nestedParameter = Expression.Parameter(Expression.Property(parameter, nestedProperties[0]).Type, "property");
            expression = CreateExpression<T>(nestedParameter, nestedProperties, value, operation);
            var type = parameter.Type;

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<type,bool>>(expression, parameter)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // there is either only one property or no property.
        Expression? property = parameter;

        if (properties.Count() > 0 && properties[0] != null)
        {
            property = Expression.Property(parameter, properties[0]);
        }

        expression = Expression.MakeBinary(GetExpressionType(operation), property, Expression.Constant(value));

        var type = parameter.Type;

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<type, bool>>(expression, parameter);
    }
}

private static ExpressionType GetExpressionType(string? operation)
{
    if (operation == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(operation));

    switch (operation.ToLower())
    {
        case "lt": return ExpressionType.LessThan;
        case "gt": return ExpressionType.GreaterThan;
        case "lteq": return ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual;
        case "gteq": return ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual;
        case "eq": return ExpressionType.Equal;
        case "neq": return ExpressionType.NotEqual;
        default: return ExpressionType.Default;
    }
}
```

The above program has an issue:

```
var type = parameter.Type;
return Expression.Lambda<Func<type,bool>>(expression, parameter)
```

These two lines shows an error:

> Type is a variable and cannot be used as a type

I am not sure how I can pass type of that particular parameter when I am recursively calling the same method.

Could some please provide me the guidance on how to achieve this functionality,  I want it to be generic so that I could pass different classes. `Vulnerabiltiy` is just one example.

I call the create expression method by passing the following arguments.

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Vulnerability), "vuln");
var properties = "Vulnerability.VulnCvssMetric.Score".Split(".").toList();
var operation = "gt";
var value = 5
```

CreateExpression(parameter, properties, value, operation);

Comment: `Expression.Lambda<Func<type...` - you have typo. Not `type` but `T`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv T should be different during the recursive calls, initally we would pass vulnerability, then it has to be VulncvssMetric etc. (i.e) we need to pass the type of the parameter during the recursive calls.

Comment: I have made similar powerful function. It would be easy to extend it to your needs and probably you will find something to learn.  [DynamicQueryableExtensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73473316/10646316)  -based on `FilterEquals` you can pass operation and create needed Binary Expression.